# Google Analytics landing page "/player" not working?

Tags: html, google-analytics

I recently started analyzing the traffic to our website using Google Analytics. One of the landing pages is labeled `"/player"` **(no .HTML at the end?)**. When I open the shortcut to the page, I get an error saying the page does not exist. After speaking with the Admin behind the website I am still left clueless as to what page `"/player"` is referring to?

> It is where over 50% of our traffic lands, when first visiting the site, and it has a 100% drop off rate.

Can anyone help me to what the landing page `"/player"` could be?

Comment: This is quite a broad question that isn't really specific to Google Analytics. You might be better speaking to the people behind your website to find out more about it.

Comment: please explain how this relates to google-analytics?
check that you are not using the same analytics code with multiple host names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GA code in your 404 error pages then Google Analytics will record any Url that caused the error page to display. GA does not check if the page displayed is an actual content page or an error page, and we cannot really say why people call a non-existing url in your page.

Maybe your domain name resembles some other domain that has a player-page and people have a typo when they try to call that other domain. Or somebody in your organization gave a wrong link in an ad or promotion material, and people now try to look at that url.

You should set a custom page path or a custom dimension in your error page (or maybe you already have a page title that indicates an error page) so you can filter out mistyped urls.